# Не работает скрипт на странице загруженой с помощью .load

Tags: jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Нужно, чтоб при нажатии кнопки, в блок #content подкружалась страничка со слайдером изображений из файла pic.html

Использую такой код

```
$(".scr").click(function () {

     $("#content").load("pic.html")
```

});

А это внутри файла pic.html

```
<div id="slideshow">

<ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="images/gallery/1.png" width="800" height="450" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/gallery/2.png" width="800" height="450" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/gallery/3.png" width="800" height="450" /></li>
</ul>

<span class="arrow previous"></span>
<span class="arrow next"></span>
```

</div>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>

Но слайдер не работает. Похоже, что не срабатывает script.js

При этом, если загрузить pic.html отдельно, то всё работает.

Собственно, вопрос в том, как подгрузить pic.html, чтоб скрипт работал?

Comment: не надо скрипт грузить таким образом. загрузите его один раз.

Answer (score 1):

пошарив [доки](https://api.jquery.com/load/), ничего интересного не нашел. Но проблема скорее всего в неправильно прописанном пути. На всякий случай доработайте ваш скрипт до такого вида:

```
$(".scr").click(function() {
  $("#content").load("pic.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
     if ( status == "error" ) {
        alert('ашыбка');
     }
  });
});
```

И еще. Возможно во время загрузки html кода скрипт слайдера не может отреагировать на изменения DOM дерева. Попробуйте в колбеке метода load сделать вызов скрипта слайдера

Comment: спасибо,но к сожалению не получилось.
мне сказали, что javascript, подгружаемый через Ajax, работать не будет и скрипт script.js нужно подключить отдельно

Я сделала так

$(".scr").click(function () {
         
         $("#content").load("pic.html"  , function() {
                                $.getScript( "js/script.js")
          });                    
}); 



но не помогло, увы((
видимо, что-то делаю не правильно